# Magento 1.9 - how to determine who created product?

Tags: magento-1.9, product

As in subject, is that possible with a default Magento 1.9 (unchanged)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an unchanged Magento 1.9 : this is not possible.

With Enterprise Edition, there are some admin actions logged so you can know which user did some kind of action. But not in the community edition.

Comment: Thank you mate. I was hoping there is anything but if not ... well, nothing can be done then, maybe you know if there is any module available which is adding this functionality ?

Comment: Well, there are third part extensions adding admin actions log : https://marketplace.magento.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=admin%20actions%20log but I have never tried any.